# Publishing last recieved data when Observable is Subscribed

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I have created GeoCoordinateReactiveService using Rx in Windows Phone 8.
The problem is that I need to start Geocoordinatewatcher before I Subscribe for Observable which is observing over PositionChange event.

So if position change event is fired before I subscribe for the first time I won't be getting the last data. How can I change current implementation to do so.

below is my current code:

```
 this.StatusObservable = Observable
            .FromEventPattern<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(
                handler => geoCoordinateWatcher.StatusChanged += handler,
                handler => geoCoordinateWatcher.StatusChanged -= handler)
            .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs.Status);

 this.PositionObservable = Observable
            .FromEventPattern<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(
                handler => geoCoordinateWatcher.PositionChanged += handler,
                handler => geoCoordinateWatcher.PositionChanged -= handler)
            .Select(ep => ep.EventArgs.Position);

geoCoordinateWatcher.Start();


geoCoordinateService.StatusObservable
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(this.OnStatusChanged);

geoCoordinateService.PositionObservable
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(this.OnPositionChanged);
```

Comment: Just a small note - the method names `On*` (like `OnStatusChanged`) are usually the methods in a class that **raise** events and not the ones that **handle** the event. You may want to consider renaming those methods to help with code maintenance.

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks for the point will keep a note about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Option 1

Subscribe before starting your watcher:

```
geoCoordinateService.StatusObservable
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(this.OnStatusChanged);

geoCoordinateService.PositionObservable
            .ObserveOnDispatcher()
            .Subscribe(this.OnPositionChanged);

geoCoordinateWatcher.Start();
```

Since you have given limited information, I have no reason to believe this is insufficient.

## Option 2

Use `Replay` to define an `IConnectableObservable<T>`, then `Connect` prior to starting your watcher:

```
var status = geoCoordinateService.StatusObservable.Replay(1);
var position = geoCoordinateService.PositionObservable.Replay(1);

var statusConnection = status.Connect();
var positionConnection = position.Connect();

geoCoordinateWatcher.Start();

status.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(this.OnStatusChanged);
position.ObserveOnDispatcher().Subscribe(this.OnPositionChanged);
```

This second option is necessary if you really do need to perform your subscription at a later time than you start your watcher.

Comment: I need to start geoCoordinateWatcher before subscribing because I will be creating and exposing GeoCoordinateService custom class which will have a public geoCoordinateWatcher Observable and any View Model that needs to observe over GeoCoordinate has to just subscribe it and get the last known and updated location of the user.